# AttributeError: type object ... has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django, django-models

fragment of models.py

```
class Hardware_type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(blank = False, max_length = 50, verbose_name="Type")
    description = models.TextField(blank = True, verbose_name="Description")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, max_length = 255, verbose_name = "Slug")

class Software_type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(blank = False, max_length = 50, verbose_name="Type")
    description = models.TextField(blank = True, verbose_name="Description")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, max_length = 255, verbose_name = "Slug")
```

and now

```
>>> sw = Software_type.objects.get(slug='unix')
>>> sw
<Software_type: Unix>
>>> hw = Hardware_type.objects.get(slug='printer')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Hardware_type' has no attribute 'objects'
```

I can't see why this happens. Anyone can help me?

Edit:

sorry that did not sent all the code - **problem solved.**
in another class I had

```
hardware_type = models.ManyToManyField(Hardware_type, verbose_name="Hardware Type")
```

after change from hardware_type to hw_type - works fine 
I did not know that can cause this problem.

Comment: You probably need to reload/refresh something.

Comment: What's the output of `type(Hardware_type)`?

Comment: >>> type(Hardware_type)
<class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'>

Comment: As a side note, you really shouldn't be naming classes with underscores in Python. `HardwareType` and `SoftwareType` follow the common convention.

Comment: I had this problem too.  What I did wrong was the give my serializer the same name as the model. So I changed the name of my serializer class to `class fooSerializer ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turned out that only began to work in django console,

Later I noticed that I have some old code in forms.py

```
class Hardware_type(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hardware_type
```

and thus it did not work, it was a bad day for naming classes, etc.

Answer (score 13):

If you add a custom manager to a model then the default manager at `objects` will not be created. Either add it yourself in the class definition, or stick with using the custom manager.

Comment: As this answer suggests, one can add "objects = models.Manager()" to the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me:

```
>>> hw = Hardware_type.objects.get(slug='111')
>>> hw
<Hardware_type: Hardware_type object>
```

<strike>However, using the keyword `type` might be a little dangerous, and probably you would like to avoid using it.</strike>

Comment: `type` isn't a keyword, and using it as an attribute is safe.

Comment: Although, it is a built in function.  Best to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my model's meta class had `abstract=True`
and i was using model.objects.all().
Since abstract cannot be instantiated, we cannot use this.